# Too many Commands Attached to view model making WPF application slow

Tags: wpf, performance, mvvm, datagrid

I have a view model which is displayed inside a `DataGrid`.  The view model is having 11 `ICommand`.

So if we are loading a `DataGrid` which is having more than 100 elements.
total 11*100 commands are getting created .

And it takes around 1 min to load the whole `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't associate your commands with your items by instantiating 11 commands *per item*. You  should have a single command (or 11 in your case) no matter how many items you have. The command knows which item to operate on by using a [command parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.commandparameter.aspx).

Put your 11 commands in your datagrid or window viewmodel and remove them from the item viewmodel. Bind the CommandParameter of each command to the item you would have called the command on, for example the selected item in the Datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

WPF Dynamic Context Menu  solved my problem ..
you can use  ContextMenu.ContextMenuOpening event on datagrid row to Create the commands while right click on the Row .[See this link for more information](http://stevemdev.wordpress.com/2010/02/07/wpf-dynamic-context-menu/)

Above link is for list ..you can use in same way for the DataGrid also

Answer (score 0):

It usually takes long time if you run it from the debugger. Try just exe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Dilshod... but i am running without debugger .And In Debug mode it takes more time than above

Comment: Maybe you should try data pager.

Comment: yes ..i can try for a data Pager.. but Is there any way to Create the Commands  after the datagrid is generated ..i mean when we right click on any row of the datagird all the commands created..(for now it is inside the constructor of the view model)

Comment: I think you can bind to commands after you loaded all the data.